# Why am I getting a "requires Indie (or higher) license" error while using Xamarin Community?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, licensing, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I am a European high school student who codes apps part-time. I've been using Xamarin Studio for around a year now on my Mac thanks to their amazing Student program.

It recently expired for me, so I tried to renew it, only to find out that it's now only available to American college students, but since Microsoft acquired Xamarin, I figured that the Xamarin Community version would work fine. I updated the IDE, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android and suddenly, I'm getting three different "requires indie (or higher) license" errors whenever I try to build my apps.

I suddenly couldn't build it any more and there's no way I can afford to pay nearly $2000/year, that's around ten times the budget I have for the whole project.

Will I have to redo all my work?

My question is: does Xamarin Community include all the functionalities of the Student program they had before? If I do a clean reinstall, will that help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can install community edition , it's having all the functionality

Comment: The thing is, I've already had Xamarin Studio installed on my Mac for a year and a half. Do I need to uninstall it and update Xam.iOS/Android again for Community to work?

Comment: Yes you have to uninstall ( because it's old version) & install new version it should work